# What type of asynchronous reset for flop is better ? active low or active high

Tags: fpga, asic

> Active Low Reset

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n_i)
if(!rst_n_i)
   out <= 'd0;
else
   out <= out + 1'b1;
```

> Active High Reset

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge rst_i)
if(rst_i)
    out <= 'd0;
else
    out <= out + 1'b1;
```

In an FPGA this depends on the type of FLOP of the device. But in an ASIC which type of reset is better ? Do we have any power or area advantage by using one over other.

Comment: This question appears [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. Consider asking on [Electrical Engineering StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Good discussion on the topic [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.verilog/WI1Ob8C0dzg)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the FF cell in the target technology. If the same polarity is preferred, the reset signal doesn't have to be inverted. It saves area and power, but would be negligible except in very small designs. In the tech libraries, active-low set and reset look more common to me.

Comment: Is there a quantitative data for how much area and power is saved ? I thought in large designs the impact will be more, mainly if its a flop intensive design

Comment: I don't have data. If the polarities are opposite, a synthesis tool is expected to put only one inverter and connect the inverted reset signal to all FFs.

Answer (score 0):

convention has typically been active-low....  saves power, is easier to achieve OFF than ON, better noise immunity.  Also, especially if using asynchronous resets, you have less issues with timing as it is easier to pull to a "0" than it is to ramp up to a "1".  Most of these types of the latter issues aren't as big a concern as they once were, but it is always good to save power